geom_abline in presence of scale_y_continuous(trans= "log10")
I use geom_abline with different intercepts and slopes and this works as expected. But adding a log scale to the axis with scale_y_continuous(trans= "log10") not only changes the axis itself but also where on the axis the line of geom_abline is. See here:
df <- data.frame(x= -5:5, y= -5:5)

ggplot(data= df, mapping= aes(x= x, y= y)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_abline(intercept= 0, slope= 0) +
  scale_y_continuous(trans= "log10")


The horizontal line is at y= 1 but I want it to be at y= 0 (as defined with intercept= 0). How to do that?

Edit
The plot above cuts off the y axis so that we dont see the point in the left bottom corner. Therefore, I wanted to change axis limits with scale_y_continuous(trans= "log10", limits = c(-5, 5)) but this does not work either, I get "'from' must be a finite number" error. So using trans= "log10" seems to apply to everything, even to the arguments in scale_y_continuous itself. How to prevent that trans= "log10" is applied on everytihng (geom_abline, limits, ...)?

y=0 is plotted at -infinity on a log-transformed axis, so I'm not sure what you're expecting!

You can't have a line at y=0 because, as @Andew Gustar indicated, there is no y=0 on a log scale. Can you give us an example with different data?

@ZéLoff Yes we can, as shown in the answer of George Savva. I simply want a horizontal line at 0. See accepted answer.

@AndrewGustar No, abline is not plotted at -Inf but at 1. This is the defeault (see accepted answer or my plot).

@ZéLoffr you could also have done it with scale_y_continuous(trans= "log10", oob = scales::squish) and then set the intercept to log(0).

@LulY George Savva's answer doesn't plot a line at log(0), it plots a line at asinh(0). If you are comfortable with the difference between the lines at his answer's last plot, by all means go for it. Just don't call it a log transformation.

@ZéLoff I clearly stated that I want no transformation on the intercept= 0 argument but a horizontal line actually being depict at 0. Further, at the same time I do want a log transformation of the axis as achieved in the answer of
George Savva

As noted in the comments, 0 does not appear on a log-transformed y axis.  You could use pseudo-log which effectively switches to a linear scale close to zero by using asinh.
df <- data.frame(x= -5:5, y= -5:5)

ggplot(data= df, mapping= aes(x= x, y= y)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_abline(intercept= 0, slope= 0) +
  scale_y_continuous(trans= scales::pseudo_log_trans(), limits=c(0,5))


Or without the limits:
ggplot(data= df, mapping= aes(x= x, y= y)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_abline(intercept= 0, slope= 0) +
  scale_y_continuous(trans= scales::pseudo_log_trans(), breaks=-5:5)


pseudo_log_trans uses the transform asinh(x/2) if you keep the default values.  If we plot this function and log (red), we can see what the difference is:
plot(\(x) asinh(x/2), xlim=c(-10,10), ylab="transformed x")
plot(\(x) log(x), add=TRUE, xlim=c(-10,10), col="red")


This makes sense given the definition, since the inverse hyperbolic function asinh is defined by:
asinh(x) = log(x + sqrt(x^2 + 1))
Which will be very close to log(2x) for large x, but for small x will be very close to x itself.

Interesting. Works as expected. Unfortunately, I have no idea whats going on under the hood. But thanks!

Looking at the code the transform is:  asinh(x/(2 * sigma))/log(base) with sigma default to 1 and base =e.  So in this case asinh(x/2)

I've made some edits to explain what it does
